# Kubernetes pods N:M scheduling how-to

Tags: kubernetes

Batch computations, Monte Carlo, using Docker image, multiple jobs running on Google cloud and managed by Kubernetes. No Replication Controllers, just multiple pods with NoRestart policy delivering computed payloads to our server. So far so good. Problem is, I have cluster with `N` nodes/minions, and have `M` jobs to compute, where `M > N`. So I would like to fire `M` pods at once and tell Kubernetes to schedule it in such a way so that only `N` are running at a given time, and everything else is kept in Pending state. As soon as one pod is done, next is scheduled to run moving from Pending to Running and so on and so forth till all `M` pods are done.

Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can have them all ask for a resource of which there's only one on each node, then the scheduler won't be able to schedule more than N at a time. The most common way to do this is to have each pod ask for a [`hostPort`](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/9030f16071f4f6d46f0482995f0db5eaf96b9294/pkg/api/v1/types.go#L802) in the `ports` section of its `containers` spec.

However, I can't say I'm completely sure why you would want to limit the system to one such pod per node. If there are enough resources available to run multiple at a time on each node, it should speed up your job to let them run.

Comment: Alex, thank you, will try. Related question: wouldn't it be easier to ask for one full CPU? If yes, how? Wrt wanting such limit: it is pure computation job, 100% cpu load, not a lot of memory. So having multiple pods fighting for the same CPU on the node is actually makes things running slower. And there is a possibility to hit node memory limit, and I don't want to ask for highmem nodes. Basically I need some simple batch scheduler from 60s mainframes...

Comment: Ah, then sure, in this case it's reasonable to run one per node. In case you are interested in using resource limits on pods instead, there's some info on how to do so in the docs: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/release-1.0/docs/user-guide/compute-resources.md

Comment: Alex, yes, I already discovered it. But I tried obvious limit "cpu": "1000m" and it didn't work out. After trial and error and binary search what worked for me was setting "cpu": "490m". Why it works I have no idea. But right now 7 node cluster is churning through ~360 jobs, some done, some pending but at any given moment only 7 are running, as I wanted it to be

Comment: Great to hear! If your VMs each have one core, part of it is likely to be consumed by the Kubernetes components running on it. I wouldn't expect it to be more than half a CPU, but that could explain it.

Comment: The link to hostPort, https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/api/v1/types.go#L537, seems broken. Could you please fix that? I'd like to read more on hostsPort

Comment: I've fixed the link. There isn't much documentation on it though, just the API definition.

Answer (score 3):

Just for the record, after discussion with Alex, trial and error and a binary search for a good number, what worked for me was setting the CPU resource limit in the Pod JSON to:

```
    "resources": {
        "limits": {
            "cpu": "490m"
        }
    }
```

I have no idea how and why this particular value influences the Kubernetes scheduler, but it keeps nodes churning through the jobs, with exactly one pod per node running at any given moment.